# Can I get the delta Cyanogenmod files?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I have a Cyanogenmod nightly build installed, and I want to update it.

Unfortunately, I don't have WiFi but only an ethernet connection, so I'll have to install it from a computer.

Is there a way to download the delta file which I get from the phone?

Comment: If you want there is a way called "Reverse Tethering", where you can use your PC's internet on phone trough cable.

Comment: @FiN aye. It is actually part of the android system (settings > wireless and networks > more > USB Tethering)

Comment: No Reverse Tethering is not. USB Tethering is where you get internet from the phone. But Reverse Tethering is where you get internet from PC to your phone.